# FileNotFoundException with getResourceAsStream() in JAR file

Tags: java, maven, jar

I don't know what to do anymore. When trying to execute my program from a runnable .jar file, I get a FileNotFoundException when trying to read my .properties file with getResourceAsStream().

I use Maven 3.5.0 and Java 8 Update 144, Eclipse Oxygen.
I also use the maven-assembly-plugin and the [assembly descriptor jar-with-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html) for producing my single .jar file.

The properties file is located in /src/main/resources (in Eclipse) as it is the convention with Maven. It is then - when building the .jar file - automatically put into the root of the .jar file.

Works perfectly when running the program in Eclipse. I just provide the name of the properties file, not other slashes (/) or anything, for the getResourceAsStream() method. I looked into the .jar file and see that the file is located directly in the root of the .jar file.

Why is the .properties file not found? I just don't get it.

**Update 2017-10-12**

I posted an answer and thought it would work, but it just seemed to work because I changed the version string and appended a "-SNAPSHOT", but since then, my submodule does not get updated. 
I understood that I just have to append the literal "-SNAPSHOT" in order for Maven to recompile the current code that I have changed in Eclipse and put it into my .jar file. But it doesn't.

Maven begins to really annoy me. It is supposed to be working like this. What the heck is now wrong?

And by the way, "mvn clean -U package" that is supposed to force an update does not update the snapshot either. I use the maven assembly plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I didn't use SNAPSHOT builds in Maven. Turns out I need to use a "[version-number]-SNAPSHOT" for the  tag so that Maven always uses the current most-up-to-date code for the build. 
Now it works. :)

**Update 2017-10-12**

OK, I think I know what went wrong. I need to run "mvn install" from my parent directory in order to invoke the compilation and installation of submodule A which submodule B is referencing as a dependency. Then I can run "mvn package" on submodule B in order to get the up-to-date code of submodule A built into the single .jar file. :)
Finally ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a slash at the beginning of your path.

```
this.getResourceAsStream('/myFile.properties')
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either. With just a slash "/", it also doesn't even work in Eclipse any more. It would then have to be a "./". But both ways don't work in the .jar.

Comment: I just realized (through remote debugging the .jar file) that for some strange reason the compiled assembly did not compile the current state of the dependency. 
I have a multi-module project, with one Server and one Client module as well as one Shared module with classes for both Server and Client.
And for some reason, the Shared project (module) does not get compiled - together with the Server - in a way that it is synced with the current state I see in Eclipse.

Which leads to the fact that I have a "./MyPropertiesFile.config" path instead of a "MyPropertiesFile.config" path.

Comment: I now need to find out why the jar-with-dependencies descriptor shown here doesn't do its job properly (so annoying).